# How to use Animation Control to play a transparent AVI?

Tags: winapi, avi

I'm using the Animation Control on a WTL dialog window, like this:

```
if (!Animate_IsPlaying(m_aviWindow))
{
    PTSTR pszAviFile = _T("C:\\build\\VS2008ImageLibrary\\Animations\\FILEMOVE.AVI");
                        //MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_AVI1);
    Animate_Open(m_aviWindow, pszAviFile);
    Animate_Play(m_aviWindow, 0, -1, -1);
}
```

The problem is that the AVI has a magenta background (RGB(254, 0, 254) and even though I respond to WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message, the AVI is not transparent.

```
LRESULT OnCtlColorStatic(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
    if ((HWND)lParam == m_aviWindow.m_hWnd)
    {
        HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
        COLORREF color = RGB(254, 0, 254);
        SetBkColor(hdc, color);
        //SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        SetPixel(hdc, 0, 0, color);
        return (LRESULT)CreateSolidBrush(color);
        return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried many possible combinations of SetBkColor/SetPixel/SetBkMode/etc, but still cannot get the AVI transparent. What am doing wrong?

Comment: The Animation Control does not support transparency. Setting the [`ACS_TRANSPARENT` Animation Control Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761886.aspx) will remap all pixels with the same color as the upper left pixel of the first frame to the **color** provided by the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`-handler. This does not produce a transparent video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your animation control, you need to specify [ACS_TRANSPARENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ACS_TRANSPARENT).  The control will then use the upper-left pixel of the first frame as the transparency color.

Comment: It's my oversight. The dialog designer in Visual Studio has both Transparent and Animation Transparent but I only changed the Transparent property which does not work. I think Transparent is inherited from STATIC control and Animation Transparent does work.